# Deploy Button is not responding

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment

I am newbie to solidity, this is my first PoC on testnet, i am just trying to understand how things works.

i am following the main tutorial on Ethereum website, under this URL https://www.ethereum.org/token

i followed all the instructions until I have reached the "How to Deploy" section. when i click on the "Deploy" button nothing is happening at all. i have closed it and running again and hit the Deploy button, nothing is happening.

below is the code i am using, it is exactly how the tutorial is asking me to do it.

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

    contract MyToken {

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyToken(uint256 initialSupply, string tokenName, uint8 decimalUnits, string tokenSymbol) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        /* Check if sender has balance and for overflows */
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value || balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to])
            throw;

        /* Add and subtract new balances */
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        /* Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place */
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }
}
```

what should i do?

Comment: Is your wallet synchronized? Does your account have enough funds?